# How do I require files in Firefox extension (add-on)?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

We created extensions for Chrome, Firefox and Safari. Our Firefox extension has a tracker, tracker.js, which is required from the controller by this line:

```
tracker = require("../../firefox/tracker.js").tracker;
```

The tracker works with requiring other files, such as:

```
if (typeof exports !== 'undefined') {
    common = require("../content/src/common.js").common;
    utils = require("../content/src/utils.js").utils;
}

var tracker = new function() {
    this.ws_track = function(params) {
        params["from_extension"] = true;
        params["platform"] = common.sys.platform;
        params["version"] = utils.get_version();
        if (params["e"] === "install") {
            utils.send_get_request(common.config.urls.apis.wstrack, params, function(data) {}, 'json');
        }
    };
};

if (typeof exports !== 'undefined') {
    exports.tracker = tracker;
}
```

But, when I try to require the controller file from the tracker, I receive the following error:

```
JPM [error]   Message: TypeError: tracker is undefined
```

Here is the tracker code in this case:

```
if (typeof exports !== 'undefined') {
    common = require("../content/src/common.js").common;
    controller = require("../content/src/controller.js").controller;
    utils = require("../content/src/utils.js").utils;
}

var tracker = new function() {
    this.ws_track = function(params) {
        params["from_extension"] = true;
        params["platform"] = common.sys.platform;
        params["version"] = utils.get_version();
        var uid = controller.load_param("uid");
        if (uid) {
            params["uid"] = uid;
        }
        if (params["e"] === "install") {
            utils.send_get_request(common.config.urls.apis.wstrack, params, function(data) {}, 'json');
        }
    };
};

if (typeof exports !== 'undefined') {
    exports.tracker = tracker;
}
```

But if I don't require the controller, I receive an error that it's undefined. How can I require the controller from the tracker file? I can't unite the files because the controller file is the same for Chrome, Firefox and Safari. And the trackers are different (Mozilla didn't approve our Chrome tracker).

**Update:** I moved the controller code to the controller, and always called the tracker from the controller, and it solves this problem (the tracker doesn't use the controller). But if you find a solution to this problem, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

There is a SDK require funciton, I use it like this - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/system_child_process#Using_child_process_in_non-jpm_extensions

```
// Import SDK Stuff
const COMMONJS_URI = 'resource://gre/modules/commonjs';
const { require } = Cu.import(COMMONJS_URI + '/toolkit/require.js', {});
var child_process = require('sdk/system/child_process');

// Use it in the same way as in the example above
```

It seems it works on CommonJS modules check this out - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/Using#Importing_CommonJS_modules

There is also a `require` function in workers that can be used like this:

```
importScripts('resource://gre/modules/workers/require.js');
```